# How to access and use data from an array I guess? In C#

Tags: c#, sorting, for-loop, jagged-arrays

This is my first post... sorry in advance ...

Hope you got mercy and I am not failing in "not enough code to help" - alright then here we go.

I want to calculate the "by price the cheapest possible `flightpath` from a to b. I need to calc 2 things I would say:

- One is the `getPriceCosts` per `flightpath`
- And I have to check somewhat like `getMaxWeight` per `flightpath.getPriceCosts[][]`...?

I got 3 possible routes

1. A -> B
2. A -> C -> B
3. A -> D -> E -> B

Am I right when I say `flightpaths` are my 3 different routes they gave me and the Trip equals to the landings of the selected route.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _07_Exam_Route
{
    internal class Program
    {
        class Place
        {
            public string name;
        }

        class Hop
        {
            public double price;
            public int capacity;
            public Place[] @base;
        }

        class Route
        {
            Hop[] fplan;
        }

        Hop[][] flightpath = new Hop[3][];
        private int tripCosts;

        private void initRoutes()
        {
            flightpath[0] = new Hop[1];
            flightpath[1] = new Hop[2];
            flightpath[2] = new Hop[3];
            /* Route 0 Hop 0 // PricewithCargo@125=1x1000(+25)=1000*/
            flightpath[0][0] = new Hop
            {
                capacity = 150,
                @base = new Place[] { new Place { name = "A" }, new Place { name = "B" } },
                price = 600d
            };
            /* Route 1 Hop 0 and 1 // PricewithCargo@125=2x75(-25)+6x25=250*/
            flightpath[1][0] = new Hop
            {
                capacity = 75,
                @base = new Place[] { new Place { name = "A" }, new Place { name = "C" } },
                price = 75d
            };
            flightpath[1][1] = new Hop
            {
                capacity = 25,
                @base = new Place[] { new Place { name = "C" }, new Place { name = "B" } },
                price = 25d
            };
            /* Route 2 Hop 0, 1 ,2 // PricewithCargo@125=2x100(-75)+2x120(-115)+2x80=600*/
            flightpath[2][0] = new Hop
            {
                capacity = 100,
                @base = new Place[] { new Place { name = "A" }, new Place { name = "D" } },
                price = 100d
            };
            flightpath[2][1] = new Hop
            {
                capacity = 120,
                @base = new Place[] { new Place { name = "D" }, new Place { name = "E" } },
                price = 120d
            };
            flightpath[2][2] = new Hop
            {
                capacity = 80,
                @base = new Place[] { new Place { name = "E" }, new Place { name = "B" } },
                price = 80d
            };
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program prg = new Program();
            prg.initRoutes();
            var route = prg.findRoute(39);
        }

        int findRoute(int weight)
        { // Start
            int besteRoute = -1;
            double worstPrice = double.MaxValue;
            for (int row = 0; row < flightpath.Length; row++)
            {
                double tripCosts = 0;
                bool abbruch = false;
                for (int column = 0; column < flightpath[row].Length; column++)
                {
                    if (weight > flightpath[row][column].capacity)
                    {
                        abbruch = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tripCosts += flightpath[row][column].price;
                    }

                    if (!abbruch && tripCosts < worstPrice)
                    {
                        worstPrice = tripCosts;
                        besteRoute = row;
                    }
                }
            }

            return besteRoute;
        }//ENDE
    }     
}
```

So then how to write a method to get the amount of attempts that's needed to carry all cargo to **B** the cheapest possible way?

(in the comments I actually precalculated to see what happens with my set values already...)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Insert with code formatting (curly braces button on the editor).

Comment: So what is *your* question? Remember [SO] is not a code writing service. Please ask a specific code-related question with clear assumptions and requirements. As I see it now, not enough information exists (for example what are the contents of `Trip`) and not a clear question, other than how do I do this overall big complicated project. Are jagged arrays a requirement for some reason, or some other structure would be ok?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. There are basic [responsibilities](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) that question askers have; being new does not shield you from that, and *talking about* being new [is counterproductive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) as it does not tell us anything about **the question**. Please [edit] the question and try to ask it clearly, getting right to the point. Start by making clear: what happens when you try the code? What is supposed to happen instead?

Comment: Also, please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and show your code [properly as formatted text, not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/). We [will not transcribe it for you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040).

Comment: @JohnAlexiou   sorry i update the post today. i already found a way to kinda solve it but not exactly the way i want it to be in the first place.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This being C# you want to use a `class` to define a flight path instead of a jagged array. For example, consider the following `Route` class that contains multiple `Legs` (each being a `Trip`).

```
public class Route
{
    public Route(params Trip[] legs)
    {
        this.Legs = new List<Trip>(legs);
    }
    public List<Trip> Legs { get; }

    public int MaxCapacity { get => Legs.Min((l) => l.Capacity); }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get => MaxCapacity * Legs.Sum((l) => l.Price); }

}
```

The built-in smarts now allow you to find the smallest capacity for all the legs (maximum a route can carry), and use that to find the price of the route. All that using `LINQ` and properties, just like C# was intended to be used.

Now you can build your business logic of filtering and sorting routes easily

```
    {
        Route ab = new Route();
        // define route ab
        Route acb = new Route();
        // define route acb
        Route adeb = new Route();
        // define route adeb

        Route[] flightpaths = new Route[] { ab, acb, adeb };

        ...

        // find least cost of carrying 60 items
        int itemCount = 60;
        // filter to routes with capacity > the item count
        Route[] availRoutes = flightpaths.Where((route) => itemCount <= route.MaxCapacity).ToArray();
        // get list of prices for the routes
        decimal[] prices = availRoutes.Select((route) => route.TotalPrice).ToArray();
        // find the minimum price
        decimal minPrice = prices.Min();
        // find the index of the min. price
        int bestRouteIndex = Array.IndexOf(prices, minPrice);
        // find the best route from the filtered list
        Route bestRoute = availRoutes[bestRouteIndex];
        
    }
```